# Refresh a kendo tab strip with partial view

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have a Kendo TabStrip with multiple tabs loaded with different partial views.

How do I reload a partial view(Refresh the tab) using jquery.

I am generating the tabs using Html wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making an ajax call back to the server/controller and returning the updated view.

Then in the response of your ajax call simply find the Tab's content div by Id using JQuery:

```
$('#myTabContent).html(view)
```

So your ajax call will look something like this:

```
 $.ajax(
 {
        url: "Customer/GetCustomerTabDetails",          
        data:
        {
           customer: id, // If you need to pass any data
        },
        success: function(view)
        {

            $('#IdOfYourContentTab').html(view);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // handle error
        }
 });
```